# Is it possible to validate more than two conditions in a .find() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to validate two conditions within the function .find() as I'm able to do only one succesfully, this `<td>{contactNames?.find(data =>{return data.contact_id_customer === report.contactIdCustomer})?.nombre}</td>` is working perfect, it is giving the name of the customers instead of the customer id from the database, however, I need to do the same validation with contact_id_providers but we don't want to render it in a different column from the table but in the customer's column one as well, so we can only leave the name as name on that column.

This is the Array object contactsName list that I'm bringing from the context provider, im not able to past images.

> Array(28)0:contact_id_customer: 0contact_id_provider: 0nombre: nullpnombre: null[[Prototype]]: Object12: {contact_id_provider: 0, nombre: '464 IN-CO TELMEX G1', pnombre: null, contact_id_customer: 223}13: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 5, nombre: null, pnombre: 'ARIATEL CORP'}14: {nombre: 'AGENTES MARCA 00464', contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, contact_id_customer: 74}15: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 2, pnombre: 'A&D MONTANA CORP', nombre: null}16: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 5, nombre: null, pnombre: 'ARIATEL CORP'}17: {contact_id_customer: 0, pnombre: 'ATLANTEL INC', contact_id_provider: 6, nombre: null}18: {contact_id_provider: 67, contact_id_customer: 0, pnombre: 'ITX ETB TPBCL', nombre: null}19: {contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, nombre: 'ADRIA-DMS Telecom LLC', contact_id_customer: 303}20: {contact_id_customer: 18, contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, nombre: 'VARSATEL CORPORATION'}21: {nombre: 'AIRTIME TECHNOLOGIES', contact_id_provider: 0, contact_id_customer: 294, pnombre: null}22: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, nombre: null}23: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, nombre: null}24: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, nombre: null}25: {contact_id_customer: 0, contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, nombre: null}26: {contact_id_provider: 0, nombre: 'XXXXX   Videocon Carrier Services Limited', pnombre: null, contact_id_customer: 190}27: {contact_id_provider: 0, pnombre: null, contact_id_customer: 138, nombre: 'VASUDEV GLOBAL LTD'}length: 28[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

I have tried this way: {contactNames?.find(data =>{return data.contact_id_customer && data.contact_id_provider === report.contactIdCustomer && report.contactIdProvider})?.nombre}
But it is only returning only the names of the provider.

Here is my code from the component CDRTable:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { CdrsContext } from '../../contexts/CDRDownloadingContext';
import { CustomerContext } from '../../contexts/CustomerContext';
import { ProviderContext } from '../../contexts/ProviderContext';
import { UserContext } from '../../contexts/UserContext';
import UseAuth from '../../hooks/UseAuth';
import styles from '../stylePages/CDRDownloading.module.css'

const CDRTable = () => {


    const { getUserDetails, record } = useContext(UserContext)
    const { cdrListFiltered, getCdrsListMadeByUser, deleteCdr, getContactNames, contactNames } = useContext(CdrsContext);
    const { auth } = UseAuth();

    /*************************************
    * GETTING THE USER ID TO GET THE LIST OF REPORT REQUESTS SENT BY THE SPECIFIC USER
    //*************************************/
    // Auth.username is providing an object type user from the backend, which among the properties it contains the user id. 
    const extractedUsername = auth.username;
    // Once the user details have been loaded with the getUserDetails(extractedUsername); function which expects a username to get data.
    // I get the especific user and with the record 
    const extractedUserById = record.serie;
    //**************************************/

    /**
     * Function to mount the list of report requests made by the logged in user
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        getUserDetails(extractedUsername);
        if (extractedUserById !== undefined) {
            getCdrsListMadeByUser(extractedUserById)
        }
    }, [extractedUserById]);

    const typeReport = {
        0: 'Cliente',
        1: 'Proveedor'
    }

    const callFilter = {
        0: 'Contestadas',
        1: 'No contestadas',
        2: 'Todas'
    }

    const statusStage = {
        0: 'Recibido',
        1: 'En proceso',
        2: 'Finalizado'
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getContactNames();
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <Table className={styles.table}>
                <thead className={styles.tableHead}>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>SOLICITADO</th>
                        <th>DESDE</th>
                        <th>HASTA</th>
                        <th>TIPO</th>
                        <th>Nombre cliente</th>
                        <th>Nombre proveedor</th>
                        <th>NOMBRE</th> // Here is where I'm trying to get the name in this column
                        <th>RGIDs</th>
                        <th>FILTRO</th>
                        <th>ESTADO</th>
                        <th>PROCESO INICIADO</th>
                        <th>PROCESO FINALIZADO</th>
                        <th>OPCIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {cdrListFiltered?.map((report, reportIndex) => (
                        <tr key={reportIndex} >
                            <td>{reportIndex + 1}</td>
                            <td>{report.requestDate}</td>
                            <td>{report.startDate}</td>
                            <td>{report.endDate}</td>
                            <td>{typeReport[report.reportType]}</td>
                            <td>{report.contactIdCustomer}</td>
                            <td>{report.contactIdProvider}</td>
                            <td>{contactNames?.find(data =>{return data.contact_id_customer === report.contactIdCustomer})?.nombre}</td>
                            <td>{contactNames?.find(data =>{return data.contact_id_provider === report.contactIdProvider})?.pnombre}</td>
                            <td>{report.rgids}</td>
                            <td>{callFilter[report.callQuery]}</td>
                            <td>{statusStage[report.status]}</td>
                            <td>{report.processStart}</td>
                            <td>{report.processFinish}</td>
                            <td className={styles.buttonOptions}>
                                <Button
                                    variant='primary'
                                    className={styles.btnGuardar}
                                >
                                    <span className={styles.textButton}>Descargar</span>
                                </Button>
                                <Button
                                    variant='danger'
                                    className={styles.btnEliminar}
                                    onClick={() => handleClickDelete(report.id)}
                                >
                                    <span className={styles.textButton}>Eliminar</span>
                                </Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </>
    )
}

export default CDRTable
```

I'm a little stuck here, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to handle this type of case?

Comment: Could you please rephrase to ask a specific question? I can't decipher what you are asking.

Comment: ok Chris, I'm trying to pass two conditions within the function .find() from javascript, this is my current line of code `<td>{contactNames?.find(data =>{return data.contact_id_customer === report.contactIdCustomer})?.nombre}</td>` This is checking one condition:  if the contact_id_customer is equal to the contactIdCustomer, it will display the name of the customer instead of the ID. However, I also need to get checked another condition within the same `<td>` ; `<td>{contactNames?.find(data =>{return data.contact_id_provider === report.contactIdProvider})?.pnombre}</td>` I need to merge them.

Comment: So you want the output to be `"<nombre> <pnombre>"` as one string?

Comment: Yes, I want what @amer is trying to do get the output of the two conditions that are separated in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to concatenate the two strings?

```
      <td>
        {contactNames?.find(
          (data) => data.contact_id_customer === report.contactIdCustomer
        )?.nombre +
          ' ' +
          contactNames?.find(
            (data) => data.contact_id_provider === report.contactIdProvider
          )?.pnombre}
      </td>
```

Comment: Yes that was it! it is rendering the customers and providers in the same column, that's what I was looking for, I just got rid off `'+' '+'` and  added instead an OR ( || ). Now is rendering without nulls. Thanks a lot for your help, you made my day Chris!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question, but could this solve your problem.

```
{contactNames?
    .find(data => 
        data.contact_id_customer === report.contactIdCustomer ||                         
        data.contact_id_provider === report.contactIdProvider)
    ?.[contactNames?.find(data => 
            data.contact_id_customer === report.contactIdCustomer || 
            data.contact_id_provider === report.contactIdProvider)
    ?.nombre ? 'nombre' : 'pnombre']
}
```

Also this looks horrible and should probably be extracted into function.

```
const getName = (arr, rep) => {
    const t = arr?.find(data => 
        data.contact_id_customer === rep.contactIdCustomer ||                         
        data.contact_id_provider === rep.contactIdProvider
    )

    return `${t?.nombre ?? ''} ${t?.pnombre ?? ''}`
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think you got me right, that's what I'm trying to do, you gave some ideas, specially in the second example, extracting it to a function would be much clear, I have some questions tho, what should I do with the const "t" that was defined? and at the end what it is returning why is the "??" for?

Comment: That was a typo on my part and return statement should be `return t?.nombre ?? t.pnombre`.
Will edit my answer.
As for '??' it is nullish coalescing operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Basically if the expression (t?.nombre) is not null or undefined it returns it. In case it is null or undefined it will return second expression (t?.pnombre).

Comment: One note though, this solution will return either nombre or pnombre depending on which exists. If you want both in one string just replace return statement with return `${t?.nombre ?? ''} ${t?.pnombre ?? ''}`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I'm almost there, I'm passing the contactNames as the parameter object and trying out with a consol.log but it is showing undefined, what could be a possible reason? i expected to get the array with data.

Comment: I've updated the answer if you call the function with `<td>{getName(contactNames, report)}</td>` it should return the string if it exist

Comment: Oh, excelent I was dealing with some errors calling it, however, I'm getting one in the return of the function, I want to get both in one string, `return ${t?.nombre ?? ''} ${t?.pnombre ?? ''}` I'm using it like this, but it is giving me the following error at the curly brackets `' ; ' expected.

Comment: Just need to wrap it in "`" I think. Will update the answer. Just a note in your array for some elements pnobmre is a string but nombre is null so you might only see one in those cases.

Comment: Yeap, that's the way because the user only choses a customer or provider not both of them. so that's why I want to join those two outcomes in the same column so we don't have empty spaces on the ones that are null.

Comment: Does the last update accomplish what you looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! It is not giving me any error in the app, but it is not rendering the names from the contactNames array, the column is just empty! :( But I put exactly what was placed on the las update and also I added the `<td>{getName(contactNames, report)}</td>` but still not showing up the data